# SWIFT UINavigationController embedded in a containerView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I have a UIContainerView inside of a ViewController which will be presented as a popoverViewController.
There is a UINavigationViewController embedded inside the containerView.
there is tableViewController embedded in the navigationView which performs a segue on cell selection.

like so  [image]

when a user clicks on My sessions from the Settings table view controller a delegate method on the (Main profile View Controller)get called to update the preferredContentSize of the popoverViewController.
and when the custom backButton (<) on the UITableviewcontroller the popoverView will change size again. i managed to get it all to work via delegation
however with that being said it only works once... the delegate method from the settings table view controller doesn't get called anymore.
i think after the setting view controller performs a segue on its own the delegate to the main profile view controller is lost and doesn't get called again.

this is how it looks in run time

[image]

now the size changes on click of my sessions and returns to original size after user taps on backbutton

[image]

but afterwards the delegate method doesn't get called and the view doesn't change size like so

[image]

i am using SWIFT 2.0 and Xcode 7.01 any solution on how to retain the delegate method would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i solved it by not using the delegates method at all.
When the view controller that is supposed to change the screen size is presented i use

```
func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(true)
presentingViewController?.preferedContentSize.width = 500
}
```

and i reverse it in viewWillDisappear

i hope it helps